# How to get private executors to communicate with our scm

Tags: cloudbees

we are using jenkins-cli for private executors like this:

Command on our private build machine (linux box):

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s [cloudbees_url]-i /var/build/.ssh/id_rsa on-premise-executor -fsroot /var/build -labels myLabel -executors 1
```

But when I kick off a job on this machine, I get a permission denied error in the build:

```
conq: repository access denied. deployment key is not associated with the requested repository.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Do you know how to add the keys necessary for the build machines to talk to our SCM (We are using BitBucket)

Answer (score 1):

First try running the same commands as the Jenkins job would run, as the user which started the slave.